# jQuery to find id that corresponds with input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to find a text element that corresponds with the input value of the text field and then hide

```
<input type="text" value="" id="input1"/>
<div id="volvo"><p>HIDE volvo IF VALUE CORRESPONDS</p></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
if(input.value == "volvo"){ //need help on this part
    $("#volvo").hide();
}     
</script>
```

Comment: When should the `.value` of the `<input>` element be retrieved and evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
$("#input1").val() == "volvo";
```

**Vanilla**

```
document.getElementById("input1").value == "volvo";
```

As guest271314 also pointed out, you have no event handler to trigger the check.

You'll want something like:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input1")

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
   // if statement...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#input1').val()` to retrieve the value of the `<input>`:

```
<script>

if ($('#input1').val() === "volvo") { //need help on this part
    $("#volvo").hide();
}
</script>
```